# Show images from folders with same name but different path

Tags: php, image, path, display

How would I display all the pictures from `lost` folder from all of the users?
I have a path structure something like this:

```
/users/

  username1/
            lost
                 1.jpg
                 2.jpg
            found/
                 5.jpg
                 7.jpg
  username2/
            lost/
                 3.jpg
                 6.jpg
            found/
                 4.jpg
                 8.jpg
  username3/
            lost/
                 9.jpg
                 10.jpg
            found/
                 5.jpg
                 7.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach()` loop for all users:

```
foreach( $users as $username )
{
    $directory = "/users/{$username}/lost/";
    $images = glob( $directory . "*.jpg" );

    foreach( $images as $image )
    {
        echo $image;
    }
}
```

With [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) you will have an array containing all desired file ending in “.jpg”

If you want display images in html files, you have to replace `echo $image;` with the path relative to your site Document Root.

Comment: Doesn't work.I changed while loop with foreach but stil don't work

Comment: $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $id1= $row["id"];
    $user = $row["username"];

Comment: You are right, I write `while()` by mistake. I'm sorry. If the script doesn't work, your path is not correct. Check for errors to see where is the error. The script is tested as working.

Comment: i think  the problem is here:   $images = glob( $directory . "*.jpg" );.It doesn't recognise files with .jpg extension

Comment: very strange. What is your OS? Try to change glob line in ` $directory . "*" `, then, in the following line, place `var_dump( $images );` to see if glob works fine